# Backdrop for mobile with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need this kind of behavior like when we click on make we can open the next model list in the same section
[image]

Please can you help me with how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about vanilla js but u can achieve this in `ReactJS` using `react-router-dom` package. you can add `Link` to each section which will replace that modal in the section without page reloading/refreshing.

***Edit:***

I have 2 ideas to to this with vanilla js but its a bit complicated and confusing.

1. using appenChild() change section child with `onclick`.
2. adding `display: none` to all and changing `display: block` for the once to display

this will not change reload or take to new page but u will need to add js for onclick for each route/model

Comment: OP is not using react, so don't see how this answer helps

Comment: ikt but i just told him the way i knew how this was possible. he want these things to change in same section which i dont think would possible in vanilla js without reloading page or making new page for everything. and even it is possible it would really complicated to do in vanilla js.( I have 2 ideas to to this with vanilla js but its to complicated and confusing).

1. using `appenChild()` change section child with onclick
2. adding `display: none` to all and changing `display: block` for the once to display

Comment: Thank you for your ideas but Actually I don’t have option to use any other JS (like React, Vanilla or Vue) I need to achieve this in plain JS

Comment: then you should try the 2 options which i mentioned above which should work in vanilla js as u want.
I would recommend 2nd option which would be easy than the 1st one to implement.

Comment: @ketakiWarule  vanilla means plain old default javascript with no extra libraries/frameworks